# Is it good practise to call Callback methods manually to initialize defaults?

Tags: java, android, listener, android-preferences

I came across a android *Preference Activity* (for supporting devices lower than *3.0* its used rather than the new *Preference Fragment*)

In the sample code below to display the currently selected value in summary for the first time ,they make a call to the `onPreferenceChange(..)`,which is the callback method in this case manually .

Though I understand the whole process now it took me long to figure out what was going on because I'm new to android and i never used to call listeners such as `actionPerformed(...)` in the `ActionListener` *class* etc directly .

***Is this bad practice ?*** , any good alternatives to this ?.

**SettingsActivity.class**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);

// For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
// updated when the preference changes.
        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));//used here similar to a view id
        //getString(R.String...) extracts the string value from strings.xml
    }
    /**
     * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
     * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
     * is changed.)
     */
    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
// Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
// Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
// current value.
        onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
// For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
// the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            }
        } else {
// For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```